# "You have no idea how X works"

Tags: discussion

I intend to start labeling this particular statement as rude or offensive. Would that be outside the rules?  I do not find it personally degrading, but in my experience, it is the beginning of the end of attempts to make sense.

It is a marker for irrational defensiveness and is often followed up by vicious ad-hominem attacks and things which are more directly rude or offensive.

No one uses it as a free-standing argument unless they can't give an explanation for how X works, even via a reference, even one possible explanation among many, which implies they don't know, themselves, and have not thought about it.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure why this got overlooked. I definitely agree that comments like this are unnecessarily rude and not in any way helpful or relevant. So, please flag these comments as such. If there is some useful text there, the rudeness can be edited out; otherwise, the whole comment can be removed.

On a related note: lately, there have been some people asking a question and directly adding "If you don't understand what I'm talking about, you don't need to reply". I believe the same applies to these cases. If you see something like this, please edit it out. (And if the OP cannot make his question clear to the majority of our users, it should be closed as unclear what you're asking.)

Comment: i never said anything like that, if you're implying that of me. i say "if you don't understand, then please say, even say why"

Comment: @MATHEMETICIAN no, I'm not implying anything of you.